# Is there such a thing as a Jsp diagram?

Tags: jsp, diagram

I am working on an existing web application. It makes good use of jsp reuse (via include or even custom tags). One of my tasks invovled make changes to these, now the affected files has climbed to more than 10, I am having a bit of trouble managing them. I was thinking to diagramming the associations of jsps and maybe even the (js and ajax scripts), is there an official way of doing it (such as UML class diagram).

I need to visualize them so that when I revisit these, I would know which screens are affected in a glance, and not relearn the associations via code rereading (if that makes any sense).

Answer (score 1):

This question can either have a very simple answer or a complicated one.

Simple:
Model them with classes stereotyped <>, or <> as swarraj suggested. Although imho, there isn't really much need to stereotype them since you could indicate that they were servlet or jsp pages just by having them realize the HttpServlet or HttpJspPage interfaces. Since most modeling tools today are rather stingy about the use of stereotypes (only one allowed - even though the most current spec allows multiple), I like to reserve the use of stereotypes for things that can not be expressed in any other way - and that have profound impact on the understanding of the model.

Complex:
Warning: I have made this topic a focus of my career lately and so my opinions are rather strong in this area - so don't take what I write too seriously :-).

When I first made the transistion to web applications from client server I wanted to apply my proven and sucessful OO best practices, but hit a minor stumbling block when it came to desgin modeling web pages (MS ASP at the time). The principal issue is that there is one conceptual web page, yet it manifests itself very differently on the server and the client. For example any given web page contains both the code to fill its dynamic content while being built on the server as well as the client scripts and hyperlinks that characterize it on the client. Mixing these two in the same class in a UML model seemed to me very confusing.

I couldn't just ignore the client side stuff, since it was (imho) architecturally significant. Navigational routes, client side scripts, forms/fields, applets, etc. were all important to me as an architect and designer - and needed to be part of the design model. The big question then became how do you properly model these types of things alongside the page creational stuff (JSP and Servlet interactions with server side resources)? The solution needed to be consistent with current Java modeling techniques, and most important at the same leve of abstraction and detail (two key modeling concepts).

The crux of the solution that I've put forward is to model these separate aspects of the web page as separate classes (one for client tier and one for server tier). They are both realized by the same component, and it is through this component realization that the concept of a page makes itself clear as a single entity. It is also through the component that URLs are realized.

Because it is a complex solution it's best that I just point you to a recent introductory article I wrote for the Jan edition of Software Development Magazine (Jan 2001). Or this older one from the Communications of the ACM (vol 42, No. 10) (which is apparently available on the net as a PDF.) Finally the shamless plug, I have written a book detailing this much further: "Building Web Applications with UML", in the Addison Wesley Object Technology Series. Although this book is pretty much focused on ASP techologies the concepts can be applied to JSP/Servlet, PHP and even CFM. I am presently working on the next edition that will include (and even focus on) J2EE imlementations.

**Courtesy- http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=334159**